# How to add new rows when archiving a row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, archive

I currently have working code inside of my Google Sheet. The code moves certain rows in the sheet over to another sheet when labeled as "Archive" in a drop down menu.

The problem I have is that when this happens, the entire row gets deleted. I only need the information from column C:O (C2:O) to be archived. Another problem that this creates, when it deletes the row the other rows move up, thus deleting the set amount of rows I have created for input.

I need it to automatically replace the archive rows with another row with all the same conditional formatting and functions so that it does not disrupt the rest of the sheet and there is no need to go in and manually create more rows.

Please help, thank you very much in advance.

Current code used in Google App Scripts is attached below.

```
function myFunction() {
 // moves a row from a sheet to another when a magic value is entered in a column
 // adjust the following variables to fit your needs
 // see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/ehoCZjFPBao/discussion
 var sheetNameToWatch = 'Campaigns';
 var columnNumberToWatch = 6;
 // column A = 1, B = 2, etc…
 var valueToWatch = 'Archive';
 var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = 'Archive';
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
 if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
   var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
   var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
   sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
   sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
 }
}
```

Comment: Here is a view-able link to the sheet 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w19StsU2Mvclrl-vDTUS1zrAjkGxrekVFV9zLNpyZ6g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your link is not public.

Comment: Thank you. Just changed it
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w19StsU2Mvclrl-vDTUS1zrAjkGxrekVFV9zLNpyZ6g/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the values without deleting the row, you'll want to change your approach in the following ways:

- obtain a Range which includes the data you want to archive
- to populate the archive sheet, use `copyTo()` instead of `moveTo()`
- obtain a Range which includes ***only the cells you want to clear out***
- use [`range.clearContent()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) to clear that range

Here's a reimplementation of your function. I've extracted the configurable bits into global variables, which makes adjusting them down the line a bit easier to do.

```
var SOURCE_SHEET_NAME = 'Campaigns';
var TARGET_SHEET_NAME = 'Archive Campaigns';

// The cell value that will trigger the archiving action.
var ARCHIVE_VALUE = 'Archive';

// The column number where you expect the ARCHIVE_VALUE to appear.
var ARCHIVE_COLUMN_NUMBER = 4;

// The starting and ending columns for the range of cells to archive.
var ARCHIVE_START_COLUMN = 1;
var ARCHIVE_END_COLUMN = 15;

// The starting and ending columns for the range of cells to clear.
var CLEAR_START_COLUMN = 1;
var CLEAR_END_COLUMN = 10;

function archiveRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCellRange = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() != SHEET_NAME ||
      activeCellRange.getColumn() != ARCHIVE_COLUMN_NUMBER ||
      activeCellRange.getValue() != ARCHIVE_VALUE) {
    return;
  }

  var activeCellRow = activeCellRange.getRow();

  // Get the range for the data to archive.
  var archiveNumColumns = ARCHIVE_END_COLUMN - ARCHIVE_START_COLUMN + 1;
  var archiveRowRange = sheet.getRange(activeCellRow, ARCHIVE_START_COLUMN, 1, archiveNumColumns)

  // Get the range for the archive destination.
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(TARGET_SHEET_NAME);
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, archiveNumColumns);

  // Copy the data to the target range.
  archiveRowRange.copyTo(targetRange);

  // Get the range for the data to clear.
  var clearNumColumns = CLEAR_END_COLUMN - CLEAR_START_COLUMN + 1;
  var clearRowRange = sheet.getRange(activeCellRow, CLEAR_START_COLUMN, 1, clearNumColumns);

  // Clear the row.
  clearRowRange.clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Awesome, so this worked thank you chuckx. But now how do I get it to only pull the columns C:O? I do not want it to disrupt or pull information from columns A or B.

Comment: If you want to archive/clear a subset of the row, change the [`sheet.getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) call appropriately. I've updated the code snippet to start with column 3 (aka column C).

Comment: To do this more simply, use the [Range.clearContent() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent).

Comment: I added a whole new answer below. I didn't realize that the @ sign wouldn't grab your username in the post.

Comment: FYI, when following up on your question, you should **edit the question** instead of submitting an answer.

Comment: Regarding your follow up question, you need to provide more details about which cells in a given row need to have their content cleared and which should be left alone (in order to preserve the formula contained within the cell(s)). Depending on what you need done, you will probably need to fetch more specific ranges to facilitate clearing only a subset of the cells in a given row.

Comment: Got it thank you for the advice. As far as the cells, I would need to fetch all cells from A-N, starting at A4 (A4:N). The columns that have a formula in them are K, L, M, N; and the columns with Data Validation are B & D. All the columns have conditional formatting.

Comment: Your new description ("I would need to fetch all cells from A-N...") conflicts with what you have in the original question ("I only need the information from column C:O (C2:O)"). This makes providing a concrete answer very difficult. As mentioned before, if you want to clarify this question, **edit the question**. If you have a new question, **ask a new question**. When you're provided a solution to your question, **accept the answer** (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Sorry Chuck. I tried to explain in my re-post that I moved the sheet around to make it view straight across so that I do not need to start at C. As you explained, I should not have answered my own questions and it was deleted by a moderator. Now the cells that I do need, go straight across the sheet without anything getting in the way. That is why I now need A4:N.

Here is the link to the sheet so you can see what I am saying.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w19StsU2Mvclrl-vDTUS1zrAjkGxrekVFV9zLNpyZ6g/edit#gid=1523539780

Comment: I've updated the answer to cover your clarifications. You should edit the question so that other readers have the full context without having to read through the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use copyTo() [1] function instead of moveTo() [2] function which is cutting and pasting the source row. Also, you need to remove the deleteRow function if you just want to leave the row cells with same format and functions set. You only would need to change this:

```
sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
```

To this:

```
sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);
```

Moreover, if you just want to copy the values and not the formulas from the cells to the target sheet, use the copyTo function with options [3], like this:

```
sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#movetotarget

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-copypastetype-transposed

Comment: Thank you Andres Duarte